# OpenLDAP ACL's using sets

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

So, I am attempting to write some LDAP rules that will allow certain people the ability to write some subtrees.

Let's say we have this user:

```
dn: uid=minion1,o=mycompany,ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
isAdmin: TRUE
```

And this user:

```
dn: uid=minion2,o=mycompany,ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
isAdmin: FALSE
```

Oh, and this user:

```
dn: uid=minion3,o=notmycompany,ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
isAdmin: FALSE
```

I'm attempting to set permissions for minion1 to modify minion2's account, but not minion3 (if you look, minion3 is in a different organization "notmycompany" where the other two are in "mycompany").

The basic rule is that a user should have the ability to add/modify/delete entries in its organization based on if the "isAdmin" property set to TRUE, AND if the object is in the same organization as the user he/she wishes to modify.

My partially working ACL is:

```
to dn.regex="^.+o=([^,]+),ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain$" 
by set="user/isAdmin & [TRUE]" write
```

This will of course allow them to modify minion3's account as well. I would like to add

```
"[^.+,o=$1,ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain$]"
```

to the by line above, but so far I have failed miserably. Does anyone have any good ideas I might try? (Did I explain what I'm attempting to do here adequately)?

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent some time looking through the [documentation on sets](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1133.html), and the problem you've got is that set operators (like `&`) really only work on data of the same type...so you can ask for the intersection of a DN and a DN, or an attribute value and a string, but intersections of things of different types doesn't make sense.

So, we build a string using the `isAdmin` attribute and the wonders of string concatenation, like this:

```
olcAccess: {1}to dn.regex="o=([^,]+),ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain$" 
    by set.expand="([admin=] + user/isAdmin + [,] + user/-1) & ([admin=TRUE] + [,o=$1,ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain])" write 
    by * break
```

Note the user of `set.expand`, because we want to use `$1` in the set definition, and note the use of `[...]` to put literal values into the strings we're evaluating.

For someone logged in as `minion1`, this will ask for the intersection of:

```
admin=TRUE,o=mycompany,ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain
```

and the literal value:

```
admin=TRUE,o=mycompany,ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain
```

Which is a nonempty set, so it works. For someone with `isAdmin=FALSE` (or no `isAdmin` attribute), the comparison would be with `admin=FALSE,...` or `admin=,...`.  Similarly, for someone not in the same organization `o=...` as the target, the intersection will produce an empty set.

If you're interested, [this](https://gist.github.com/larsks/6217502) is what I actually used for testing.  I'm using `employeeType` instead of `isAdmin` because I didn't want to muck about with adding a new attribute to my schema.

Also: `slapd -dacl ...` is your friend.

Comment: While it smells like a bit of hack this was totally fun to figure out.

Comment: That was a great answer. I did modify your example above because [admin]=user/isAdmin was not turning out to match [admin=TRUE]. So, I just modified it to read:
set.expand="(user/isAdmin + [,] + user/-1) & ([TRUE] + [,o=$1,ou=cust,dc=some,dc=domain])" and viola.

Thanks again for the great answer!

Comment: Whoops, that's because there should be a `+` in there; I've updated the answer.